# How i make my script create the doc in a folder not the root directory in google drive

Tags: scripting, google-drive-api

I have a script that merger some google docs, but it create the file in the root dir, i want the script to add it into a existing folder.

[Code](https://script.google.com/macros/d/MVIblEijZrKZ1L_aHC9An52xMYCeUYLF8/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvEdbxw4JGwfSWGgF96rDCc2NWzTHw0jFgCMhHVIaV8erUv4vhs1FTnO53cckuqtLb6QTL3GR1GMdU5Av-no64vgOLTrqWtp4BD5Tw1CyLi5e5sNCdZr6OFf7hZ_9ASIL14Q-6Twqo0)

Sorry im new to this..How do i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to achieve this using Apps Script.

You could use Apps script's [DriveApp.getFolderById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFolderById(String)) method to get the required folder. Also [DocumentApp.create()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#create(String)) method  to create a document.

Please find the working example to create a file in specific Drive folder:

```
function createDoc()
{
  var targetFolder =  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var newDoc =  DocumentApp.create('My file1');
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc.getId());
  targetFolder.addFile(file);
}
```

Tried and tested the code.
If you want to create a Spreadsheet file, you just use [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#create(String)) instead. Hope that helps!